# When linking to ID, element appears underneath header

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development, mostly just trying to teach myself how with internet tutorials and such. I'm a complete newbie, so this might be a dumb question, but I've searched google up and down, and have yet to find an answer.

Basically my problem is, I've created a web page with `position: fixed;` header at the top of the page. I've adjusted the margins of the page so that everything seems to look great. The page displays exactly as I intended it to.

However, I've come across a small flaw which I find myself incapable of fixing: I have a few links on the page that link to specific headings elsewhere on the same page. (For example, I have an element such as `<section id="section_3">...</section>`, and elsewhere on the same page I'm using `<a href="#section_3">...</a>`. It works and leads me to the appropriate header, but unfortunately the top of `<section>` element I linked to (mostly just the section heading) is being covered up by the fixed header at the top of the page, so I have to scroll up a little to read the section header. I've tried linking to an `<h1>` rather than a `<section>` element, thinking it might be incompatibility with html5 or some such, but I have the same problem that way too.

I'd like to have it so that the section header is the first visible element under the header when I follow these ID links. How can I do this? I would assume this is a common enough situation that there would be a simple fix to it, but I can't seem to find anything on the subject. (I have no issues using html5 or css3. Currently this is just a personal project, and by the time I'm making anything public I expect it will be far enough down the road that there won't be any issue using those. For the time being, it only needs to work on my browser.)

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding @johnniebenson comment, add the css like this for the related section. Let suppose the header's height is 60px and you would like to give some space below header about 40px then do this. Example: `#section_3:target{ padding-top: 100px;margin-top: -100px}`

Comment: This did exactly what I need, and also doesn't change the layout of my page at all, which is perfect. I just made a slight modification by just using `:target` rather than `#section_3:target` so I didn't have to do separate css for each ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `padding-top` of each `section` equal to the height of your `header`. Then link to the `h1` in each `section`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This exactly what I needed. However, it has the unfortunate side effect of making the spacing between my sections a little bigger than I'd like. Is there a way that doesn't do that?